# Tweeter bot with Ruby bot.rb:4:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `twitter' for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: ruby, twitter, bots

I'm trying to build a small twitter bot following a tutorial 
but I got this error "bot.rb:4:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method`twitter' for main:Object (NameError)"

My code is

```
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'twitter'

 client = twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
 config.consumer_key = ""
 config.consumer_secret = ""
 config.access_token_secret = ""
end
```

source 'https://rubygems.org'
   ruby "~> 2.6.0"

```
gem 'twitter'
gem 'activesupport'
gem 'actionview'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'rake'
```

Comment: the tutorial : http://jenniferkruse.me/twitterbot.html

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the documentation that you mentioned, name of classes should starts from the capital letter, so in your case: `Twitter::REST::Client.new`, not `twitter::REST::Client.new`.

I suggest you to learn basics of Ruby, it will help you further. ;)